# Pipe sed capture group through external program before replacing?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, replace

Is there a way for `sed` to pipe a capture group to another program,  making `\1` in the regexp's RHS equal to the output of that program?

For example, running

```
sed 's/lorem ipsum \(foobar\)/\1/g' file.txt
```

would pipe "foobar" through another program (e.g., `tr 'o' 'a'`) to make `\1` be "faabar" for `sed` to replace "lorem ipsum foobar" with "lorem ipsum faabar"?

<sup>This is just a simple example. I realize I could convert "foobar" to "faabar" without using `tr`.</sup>

Comment: Not sure about sed, but I know that could be done with Perl. Though if the filter program is simple enough, it might be easier to implement it within the same Perl script. What does your filter actually do?

Comment: Crossposting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58576874/3776858

Comment: Crossposting: https://superuser.com/q/1496340/340330

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question within the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can with GNU sed - using the `e` (execute) modifier:

> e
>  
>   This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into
>   pattern space. If a substitution was made, the command that is found
>   in pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced with its
>   output. A trailing newline is suppressed; results are undefined if the
>   command to be executed contains a NUL character. This is a GNU sed
>   extension.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command))</sup>

but it has limited usefulness since it executes and replaces the whole pattern space, rather than specified capture groups. So you would need to jump through some pretty ugly hoops.

Ex.

```
$ echo 'lorem ipsum foobar' | sed '
    s/\(lorem ipsum \)\(foobar\)/printf "%s%s" "\1" "$(echo "\2" | tr o a)"/e
  '
lorem ipsum faabar
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know: no.

It is possible to write the pattern space to a file using

```
sed  '/example/w file'
```

but not the capture group. You can execute an external program with

```
sed 'e ls'
```

and you can read a file with

```
sed 'r file'
```

but I do not see a maintainable way to do what you are asking. And frankly, you are at the border of usefulness of `sed` here.

`awk` might be a bit more flexible here, but this is the place where `perl` is your best option, as @ikkachu already suggested in his comment.

As a short idea of how trivial it is in `perl`:

```
while (<>){
    if (/(.*)(pattern)(.*)/){
        $pre=$1;
        $pat=$2;
        $post=$3;
        $repl=`filter_pgm $pat`;
        print $pre . $repl . $post;
    }
    else {
        print;
    }
}
```

(for those more versed in Perl: I know it is ugly and may need quite a bit of polishing before running in production)